# User control properties C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, user-controls

I've created custom properties for my user controls.

My user control:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="BtnPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" PostBackUrl="~/Page1.aspx"/>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button2" PostBackUrl="~/Page2.aspx" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Property:

```
public bool ShouldBeVisible
{
    get
    {
        return Button1.Visible;
    }
    set
    {
        Button1.Visible = value;
    }
}
```

And in Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Visible = ShouldBeVisible;
}
```

In page1.aspx using the UC:

```
<uc:MyUserControl runat="server" />
```

If I want to use the property on another button (eg. Button2), how can I re-use the ShouldBeVisible property?

**EDIT: Sorry, but the ShouldBeVisible property I want to use on the Buttons, not the UC declaration. Depending on which page (page or page2) I want to show Button1 or Button2.**

Comment: You mean you don't want `return Button1.Visible` but instead `<uc:MyUserControl ID="MyUC" associatedControl="Button2" />` and then in code `return AssociatedControl.Visible`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the property of your `UserControl` in such a way so that it can be used for multiple controls not only for `Button1`. Here is one way to do this

```
private bool _shouldBeVisible = false;
public bool ShouldBeVisible
{
   get
   {
      return _shouldBeVisible;
   }
   set 
   {
      _shouldBeVisible = value;
   }
}
```

And then you can write something like this on your `Page_Load` of UC.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button1.Visible = Button2.Visible = ShouldBeVisible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to introduce another property:

```
<uc:MyUserControl Visible="<%# Button1.Visible %>" />
```